# Pass an expression as a function argument in R

Tags: r, function, expression

I'm trying to write a function which will accept an expression consisting of one or more column names as in the below:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1 , 2 , 3) , b = c(1 , 2 , 3))
beans <- function (data , expr) {
    with(data , expr)
}
```

The desired output is something like:

```
beans(data , expression(a + b))
# [1] 2 4 6
```

but this instead returns

```
expression(a + b)
```

Ideally, a solution would allow a single column to be used as an argument as well, e.g.

```
beans(data , a)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `eval` (even outside the function):

```
with(data, eval(expr))
eval(expr, envir = data)
```